# Mismatched encodings porting procedural gradient generation from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, gradient, porting, procedural-generation

I'm replicating the tinyrenderer project by Dmitry V. Sokolov from C++ to C# and am unable to replicate one of the most basic functions he has written to generate a gradient image procedurally. I have a feeling that differences in the character encodings used by the two languages are behind it.

The original function is at https://github.com/ssloy/tinyraytracer/wiki/Part-1:-understandable-raytracing#step-1-write-an-image-to-the-disk and the relevant portions are quoted below.

```
std::ofstream ofs; // save the framebuffer to file
ofs.open("./out.ppm");
ofs << "P6\n" << width << " " << height << "\n255\n";
for (size_t i = 0; i < height*width; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j<3; j++) {
        ofs << (char)(255 * std::max(0.f, std::min(1.f, framebuffer[i][j])));
    }
}
```

And the output looks like this.

[image: Original gradient image]

My own code is written in C#.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("out.ppm", FileMode.Create))
{
    var header = $"P6\n{width} {height}\n65535";
    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header);
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    var pixels = new byte[3];
    for (var index = 0; index < height * width; index++)
    {
        var point = frameBuffer[index];
        pixels[0] = (byte)(255 * Math.Max(0.0f, Math.Min(1.0f, point.Item1)));
        pixels[1] = (byte)(255 * Math.Max(0.0f, Math.Min(1.0f, point.Item2)));
        pixels[2] = (byte)(255 * Math.Max(0.0f, Math.Min(1.0f, point.Item3)));

        stream.Write(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
    }
}
```

My output looks like this.

[image: Incorrect gradient]

My reading of C++ is a bit rusty, so I might be doing something fundamentally wrong in my port. Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: log intermediate results and compare them

Comment: Your C# translation seems correct, if a little inefficient. I would guess that the values in `frameBuffer` are different. EDIT: Although it seems you've set the max value in the header to 65535 instead of 255.